# Program to find prime numbers is returning no numbers?

Tags: java

```
public ArrayList Numbers(int upper, int lower)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean decider;
    for(int x = lower; x <= upper; x++)
    {
        decider = true;
        for(int y = 2; y < upper; y ++)
        {
            if(x % y == 0)
                decider = false;
        }
        if(decider == true)
            primeNumbers.add(x); 
    }
    return primeNumbers;
}
```

I wrote the following code to determine if a number is prime. My thinking is if i default a boolean to true and a number divided by another number has a remainder of 0, then the boolean is set to false.

```
for(int x = lower; x <= upper; x++)
    {
        decider = true;
        for(int y = 2; y < upper; y ++)
        {
            if(x % y == 0)
                decider = false;
        }
        if(decider == true)
            primeNumbers.add(x); 
    }
```

For this section here, that is what I attempted to do. Every number between the upper and lower bounds is checked to see if any division has a remainder of 0. If it does, the boolean is false and it is not added to my array.

For some reason the array is recieving no numbers between the upper and lower bounds. I cannot spot the problem. Can anyone else?

Edit- I edited this post after finding another error because the program went from returning all values to none at all.

Comment: Replace `if(decider = true)` with `if(decider)`.  There may be other problems, but this should definitely change the behavior.

Comment: I am not sure how to reply directly Tim, but thank you so much for finding that error. However I fixed it an ran the program and now I am not getting any outputted numbers. Can you see another mistake?

Comment: Why not `if(new BigInteger("7").isProbablePrime(1)){  }`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Using an existing method to find a prime probably isnt a a good learning exercise

Comment: @flakes Agree! But it is probably a better idea to view the source to understand it ;)

Comment: I found the error. for(int y = 2; y < upper; y ++) should be for(int y = 2; y < x ; y ++)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I am in a introductory computer course so I am supposed to make my own programs. It is a great suggestion though.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I get what you're saying, but the implementation of `isProbablePrime` in the `BigInteger` class is in no way going to readable by a beginner. It is a chunk of dense math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logical problem I see with your code.  Your inner `for` loop in `y` will cover most of the time a range which *includes* the value of `x`, since the loop's upper bound is also `upper`.  So, in most cases, you would be counting a number divisible only by itself as being not prime, when in fact it is.  You should stop that loop before reaching the target `x`.  And also, you may break if you find a divisor.

```
for(int x = lower; x <= upper; x++) {
    decider = true;
    for (int y = 2; y < x; y ++) {   // can probably make this bound even tighter
        if (x % y == 0) {
            decider = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (decider)
        primeNumbers.add(x); 
}
return primeNumbers;
```

Here is a demo showing that the above logic works correctly:

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are writing the wrong arguments when scanning through y. 
Observe:

```
public ArrayList Numbers(int upper, int lower)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean decider;
    for(int x = lower; x <= upper; x++)
    {
        decider = true;
        for(int y = 2; y < x; y ++)
        {
            if(x % y == 0)
                decider = false;
        }

        if(decider = true)
            primeNumbers.add(x); 
   }
   return primeNumbers;
}
```

Of course you could improve your code by keeping the upper bound of y as the sqrt(x) + 1 and adding y by increments of 2 instead of 1. You need to check the base case of the number 2 separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem is:

```
for(int x = lower; x <= upper; x++)
```

When you iterate until <=upper,  it also divides the number by itself, and messes up your results.

Change it to "<" and it'll work;

```
public ArrayList Numbers(int upper, int lower)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean decider;
    for(int x = lower; x < upper; x++)
    {
        decider = true;
        for(int y = 2; y < upper; y ++)
        {
            if(x % y == 0)
                decider = false;
        }
        if(decider == true)
            primeNumbers.add(x); 
    }
    return primeNumbers;
}
```